# Interpretation of Multiple Change point results and graph for offline analysis in R

Tags: data-visualization, change-point

Using the changepoint R package to detect and estimate multiple change points with non-normality assumption for mean with the following codes

```
out2<-cpt.mean(q[,2],penalty="BIC",pen.value=0.02,method="SegNeigh",Q=5,test.stat="CUSUM",class=TRUE,param.estimates=TRUE,minseglen=1)
```

The results is, 
Changepoint type      : Change in mean

Method of analysis    : SegNeigh

Test Statistic  : CUSUM

Type of penalty       : BIC with value, 2.080237

Minimum Segment Length : 1

Maximum no. of cpts   : 5

Changepoint Locations :

Range of segmentations:

```
   [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
```

[1,]      0      0      0      0      0

[2,]   1937      0      0      0      0

[3,]     10      5      0      0      0

[4,]     14     10      5      0      0

[5,]    384    382    377    266      0

For penalty values: 0 0.01702072    0.04016257    0.08605699    0.1370768

```
plot(out2)
```

[image]

How could find out the location for change-points from this output? What does the graph telling about change-points?

CPM package for fixed (offline) data gives one change point on the location 2653. However, it can't handle for multiple change-point in offline procedure.

library(cpm);
detectChangePointBatch(q[,2], "Mann-Whitney", alpha=0.05, lambda=NA);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the output is telling you is the following:

- There are no changepoints detected with the penalty used (hence blank on "changepoints" field)
- The penalty value you entered (0.02) was not used as you specified BIC which gives a penalty value of  2.080237.
- The plot reiterates this with a single horizontal line for the mean with no breaks in it.

If you want to use a penalty of 0.02 then you should put `penalty="Manual"` in the function call.

However, you don't need to play with the penalty as the "Range of Segmentations" in the output tells you that if there is 1 changepoint it is at 1937, for 2 they would be at 10 and 5 etc.
You can change Q to get more segmentations listed.